# No "short" replacement on windows batch parameters

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to iterate through a folder and check if some file exist in its subfolders. Some of these subfolders may have braces so I used the short name replacement of batch parameters (see `call /?`):

```
@echo off
for /D %%D in (*.*) do (
  call :showFile "%%D\nbproject\project.properties"
)
pause
goto :eof
:showFile
echo F: %1
echo S: %~sdp1%~nx1
goto :eof
```

This approach works just fine on most of our systems (all Windows 7 pro). On a "new" Laptop this stops to work. The "`S:`" line shows the full "real" Path instead of the short one.

Subsequent commands in the original batch file throws errors because of the extra braces from the folder names. It is not possible to use double quotes in this commands so I am stuck to use the short path.

What setting prevent this replacement to work propertly?

Comment: You could check the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem\NtfsDisable8dot3NameCreation`

Comment: You are actually talking about parentheses `(`/`)`, aren't you? Note that these `{`/`}` are called braces (or curly brackets), and these `[`/`]` are called (square) brackets...

Answer (score 3):

As the 8.3 short names can be disabled, you could build a solutions which is stable for all long names.

You should always quote your variables and or switch to delayed expansion to avoid problems with braces at all.

```
for /D %%D in (*.*) do (
  set "filename=%%~D\nbproject\project.properties"
  call :showFile
)

:showFile
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
if exist "!filename!" echo !filename! exists
```